# When is Sympy/Ipython Automatically subscripting coefficients for display?

Tags: python, sympy

Below I show that Sympy/IPython is adding subscripts to the latex of `a0` before displaying it. I've tried to look into the source code but I can't find where this is done?
Ideally, I would like to have access to this latex string variable to modify or at least stop this behaviour, so I can handle all the subscripts manually.

In contrast, the variables `an` and `a1` behave straightforwardly. The latex of `an` is just the string and `a1` maintains the subscript I manually give it.

```py
from sympy import *
a0, an, a1 = symbols('a0 an a_1')

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
display(InteractiveShell.instance().display_formatter.format(a0))
display(InteractiveShell.instance().display_formatter.format(an))
display(InteractiveShell.instance().display_formatter.format(a1))

print(latex(a0))
print(latex(an))
print(latex(a1),"\n")

print(str(a0))
print(str(an))
print(str(a1))

display(a0)
display(an)
display(a1)
```

[image]

#### Examples showing my confusion over this behaviour

Can I make a variable `xh` where `print(xh)` gives 'xh' but `latex(xh)` gives `x_{h}` (and thus display will produce a subscript) just like `a1` above. Alternatively, how can I stop this behaviour? What if I want the variable `a1` with `latex(a1)` giving `a1` not `a_1`?

**Other Information**

IPython 7.20.0, SymPy 1.7.1, Python 3.8.8

My context is programmatically handling lots of left and right subscripts of sympy variables and this automatic behaviour is getting in the way. However, I think it's reasonable to discuss the behaviour above in its own right.

**Edits:** Added `str()` and `latex()` of variables. Added extra section explaining my lack of understanding with an example.

Comment: The `symbols` function supports range indexing, like with `symbols('a1:4')`.  The docs link this specifically to the use of the colon,  `symbols('a:4')`, but `symbols('a1')` may be a subcase of that.  `symbols` is a complicated function that takes a string (or strings) and generates multiple `Symbol` objects, with various range shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However symbols creates these "indexed" variables, which are different to those created by `Indexed()`, and I want to know where the difference is. Where is that subscript stored - it isn't there in the string shown in `str()`.

Comment: `a0`, the python variable, is a `sympy.Symbol` object, which is a subclass of more basic `sympy` classes.  The `str` (and `repr`) is defined by the class, and is just a string display.  It does not display all attributes of the object.  Evidently there are underlying differences between `a0` and `a1` even though the latex display is similar.  How `sympy` displays its objects is a complex subject.

Comment: That makes sense, how can I make other variables like this? Is there a way to change the latex display without changing `str`? For example, can I make a variable `xh` where `print(xh)` gives 'xh' but `latex(xh)` gives `x_{h}` (and thus display will produce a subscript). Also how can I stop this behaviour, what if I want the variable `a1` with `latex(a1)` giving `a1`?

Comment: Your comments are moving beyond the original question.  I think you need to study the `sympy` docs, such as the `printing` section, which includes a `latex` section.  SO is a substitute for studying the docs.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I've read the `printing` section and there's no mention of separate printing variables and manipulating that behaviour. My original question is all along these lines "have access to this latex string variable to modify or at least stop this behaviour". Maybe I should rephrase the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question, I think this behaviour comes from `split_super_sub()`. The documentation states that the following is part of "A few practical conventions common to all printers".

In:

```py
from sympy.printing.conventions import split_super_sub
print(split_super_sub("a0"))
print(split_super_sub("an"))
```

Out:

```py
('a', [], ['0'])
('an', [], [])
```

Edited Extra Notes:
In my case, now I can then write a custom `split_super_sub` as well as a custom `LatexPrinter` alongside `init_printing(latex_printer=` to change this printing behaviour in my code